# Python aiohttp ClientSession requests memory leak?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I believe I have unearthed a memory leak in my long-lived application when using aiohttp ClientSession requests. If each coroutine which makes a request is awaited sequentially, then all seems fine. However there seems to be a leak of request context manager objects when run concurrently.

Please consider the following example code:

```
import logging
import tracemalloc
import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def log_allocations_coro():

    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(120)
        snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
        top_stats = snapshot.statistics('lineno')
        str_list = [str(x) for x in top_stats[:5]]
        logging.info("\n".join(str_list))


async def do_request():

    try:
        async with session.request("GET", "http://192.168.1.1") as response:
            text = await response.text()
    except:
        logging.exception("Request failed")


async def main():

    tracemalloc.start()
    asyncio.ensure_future(log_allocations_coro())
    
    timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=1)
    global session
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=timeout)

    while True:

        tasks = [ do_request(), do_request() ]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        await asyncio.sleep(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

The `tracemalloc` coroutine logs memory allocations every two minutes. This shows the count for allocations in `aiohttp/client.py` where `request()` returns a `_RequestContextManager` increasing over time, initially quickly but then slows until reaching a peak and then seems to be fairly stable.
*However,* It has then been observed that if there is a network problem and requests start to fail then the count ramps back up again - and doesn't come back down after the problem has been resolved.

Is this a leak? If so, is there a way to work around it?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Maybe you should post the code with tracemalloc inside, in order to give us more details to reproduce the potential memory leak. Just a thought : your code doesn't close the client.ClientSession object, so maybe, that could be a clue ?

Comment: Thanks @Julien, the tracemalloc code was left out for the sake of clarity/brevity but I could include it if it might help. You have a good point about not closing the ClientSession object, but it's a long-lived application which never exits so there isn't a point where it should be closed. That could be a potential workaround though - periodically close the session and start a new one.

Comment: Hi @Julien, I've updated the code to be a complete example.

Comment: I have no idea of the innards of aiohttp, so it _could_ be that aiohttp session is caching something. Maybe you can ask in aiohttp forums or GitHub?